# dockerd not running on nixos

Tags: docker, daemon, nixos

I installed docker on nixos, using:

```
nix-env -i docker
```

after that, dockerd was not running, so I started the daemon manually with:

```
dockerd
```

and in the logs, I see:

> WARN[2019-06-26T01:02:31.784701442Z] could not change group
>   /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found

should I care about this warning?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When installing docker on NixOS, it's best to [enable](https://search.nixos.org/options?show=virtualisation.docker.enable&query=virtualisation.docker) it in the NixOS configuration. Doing so will install docker as a system service.

Snippet for `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```bash
virtualisation.docker.enable = true;

# ...

users.users.YOU = { # merge this with your unix user definition, "YOU" is for illustration
  isNormalUser = true;
  # ...
  extraGroups = [
    # ...
    "docker"
  ];
};
```

Comment: I am pretty sure (but less than 100%) you will need to create the docker group as well.

Comment: The docker module creates the group for you: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/6702acaf561f7a1326d5745031549bb7147f1882/nixos/modules/virtualisation/docker.nix#L154

Comment: even when I add extraGroups if I run `groups` on a terminal after restarting (and running nixos-rebuild switch) the docker group is not listed under my user

Answer (score 3):

created a group `docker`. Docker needs that user group to start as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to restart your computer, and not just logout-login, to actually make sudo-less docker work.